# Zend Framework 2 - Optimal Module structure

Tags: php, module, zend-framework2

I've been working with `Django` for a while but now I've to switch to `Zend`.

My question is: When creating a new module, ie "Backend", I have for example 3 different model classes I need to manage in this backend. Do I put all the files in Backend/src/Backend/... or do I just a structure like this: Backend/src/Class1/... Backend/src/Class2...

At first I thought of a module as something similar to a Django app. But if I fork it further, it would be something like a super-app...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you do mean ZF2 and not ZF1 from your question's details:

The class namespace determines the path inside the src folder (by default). You may place the files as you like but for the autoloader to work and for others to easyly understand it would be wise to follow this convention.

Example:

```
Class Namespace: Backend\Entity
Class Name: FirstEntity
Save Path: module/Backend/src/Backend/Entity/FirstEntity.php
```

Comment: thanks, I've updated the question. But why do I need the second "Backend" within the src dir?

Comment: Zend 2 follows PSR-0 for autoloading. PSR-0 requires the namespace to represent the path in the filesystem. The base path for PSR-0-autoloading is Backend/src so you will need a folder for the top level namespace there. See also: https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md

Comment: ok, but this explains just the Backend before the "src"...right? Or did I miss something why adding the one AFTER the src?

Comment: The one before wraps the module files, the one after is required by PSR-0 for autoloading ;) You need to see "src" as the base folder. not module/Backend... module/Backend wraps src, data, public etc... All the files the module needs. src just wraps the PHP classes - a sub-portion of all the files (assets, temporary data, php classes like controllers, entities etc). This way you could implement a second namespace like BackendAdmin in this module - if this makes sense or not is another question :D

Comment: You are welcome. It would be more clear if you think of module name and module namespace as two different things - normaly they are identical through.

Comment: i tried to change my directory like this but im experiencing the following: when i just add the "entity" dir under `src` then my namespace var in the config/module.config.php links not to my entitys because the namespace is on "backend" and not "backend/entity". but if I create under module/backend/ a subfolder then i what namespace do i use in this config.php? just backend will link to the wrong entity dir... and if i have several apps then i'd need a more generic way to point to the classes? i'm lost...

Comment: I do not really understand what you are trying to achive. This also seems to be beyond the scope of comments. You may open a new question or a chat on that.